# Restore Particular tables in one schema to another schema postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, database-restore

In my case, i have backup file in full database. Now I want to restore some particulars tables in `public` schema.

Those tables are already stored in another schema. Any Feasible solution is there? and How to do it

Comment: How did you take the export (custom, plain text or "directory" format)?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am newbi in postgresql so plz show any example of export. and how to do it

Comment: There are several examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether the tables you want to restore were backed up from the schema "public", or whether they were backed up from a different schema.

If your backup is in archive format, not in a plain text format, you can restore individual tables (see the `-n` and `-t` options to [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html)). As far as I know, you can't restore them to a different schema. Instead, you'd restore them to their original schema, [then move each table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html) with `ALTER TABLE table_name SET SCHEMA new_schema;`.

Since you already have tables of the same name in the target schema, I expect you'll have to rename them before restoring from backup. After you restore from backup, and you move the restored tables to the schema "public", you can rename those tables to their original names. PostgreSQL understands that public.table_name and new_schema.table_name are different tables.